# Find a value in a range = is there such a code keyword in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

In a lot of situations we have to do something like this:

```
if (someVariable == value1 || someVariable == value2 || someVariable == value1...)
```

Would it be nice if we can do this in following manner:

```
if (someVariable in {value1, value2, value3...}
```

We can do this

```
int[] arr = {value1, value2, value3....};
if (arr.Contains(someVariable)) ...
```

But its still overwhelming, to my opinion. Why there isn't a support for this syntax, or there is but I don't know about it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this may be about as concise as you may get:

```
if (new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }.Contains(2))
{
    Console.WriteLine("bleh");
}
```

Comment: I dont know how I thought this is not possible, I am sure I have tried it. :) This is the closest to what I was expecting, altough it would be nice if Microsoft would add this in framework, so we could just do {1, 2, 3 }.Contains(2).

Answer (score 7):

Use a HashSet for this:

```
var hs = new HashSet<int>();
hs.Add(1);
hs.Add(2);
...
if(hs.Contains(x))
{
   //bingo!
}
```

Comment: Why was this voted down? It is an improvement over the array approach suggested in the question.

Comment: -1 is very harsh. so +1. btw paul, why couldn't you use a simple generic list and use `.Contains`?

Comment: @phoog My guess: Question is about syntax not the performance. `HashSet` is great when you have to find value in larg4e collection, but it seems that OP have only a few possible values. With `HashSet` aproach syntax is getting even more complicated which goes against what was asked for.

Comment: @naveen for a sizeable number of elements, HashSet is more efficient at determining whether it contains a given item.  List does a linear search, which is O(n) as opposed to O(1) for hash lookup.  HashSet is arguably simpler in this context.

Comment: @PiotrAuguscik I agree with your analysis, but I note that the hash set can also be used with collection initializer syntax.

Comment: I am not sure what this method improves over my example with array? When I said that it is overwhelming, I guess using HashSet adds to overwhelmingness even more. :)

Comment: @phoog: thank you. i know that :) op was just trying to avoid multiple or in his if condition and so my comment :)

Comment: @Goran HashSet uses O(1) hash lookup to determine whether it contains a given value, while array requires O(n) linear search.

Comment: @PaulKeister I just noticed that you used ContainsKey(), but the method's name is actually Contains().

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, especially pointing out the error in the method name. I agree that lookup efficiency is irrelevant for small data sets. The reason I proposed HashSet is probably because HashSet is a container that was designed specifically for this purpose.

Comment: @phoog In this case it does not make difference, since the question was asked in regard to if statement, which  normaly never have more than 5 conditions. What kind of performance would I gain, its not even measurable.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
switch (someVariable)
{
    case value1:
    case value2:
    case value3:
    case value12345:
        doSomething();
        break;
    default:
        doSomethingElse();
        break;
}
```

Comment: Nope, values must be constants, which is not the case in most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440.aspx) method of [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx).  I am not sure how this improves code clarity since you are still forced to check all three conditions.